# Maximizing with two arguments with iteration

Tags: optimization, proof-verification

I would like to show that:

$$
\displaystyle\max_{(x,y) \in X\times Y} f(x,y) = \displaystyle\max_{x} \displaystyle\max_{y} f(x,y)
$$

which I obviously believe to be true, although I may be wrong. $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary choice sets. $f:X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt at a proof is below.

Let:

$$
(x^*,y^*) \in \arg \displaystyle\max_{(x,y) \in X\times Y} f(x,y)
$$

Now let's consider the iterated maximization problem. Let:

$$
y^{*}_{I}(x) \subset \arg \displaystyle\max_{y \in Y} f(x,y)
$$

where I use subscript $I$ to denote "iterated". Suppose, to reach a contradiction, that:

$$
x^* \neq x^*_I, \\
x^*_I \equiv \arg \displaystyle\max_{x \in X} f(x,y^*_I(x))
$$

Since:

\begin{gather}
\{x \in X : x \in \arg \displaystyle\max_{x \in X} f(x,y^*_I(x))\} \subset \{x \in X : x \in \arg \displaystyle\max_{(x,y) \in X\times Y} f(x,y)\} \\
\{y \in Y : y=y^*_I(x); x \in \arg \displaystyle\max_{x \in X} f(x,y^*_I(x))\} \subset \{y \in Y : y \in \arg \displaystyle\max_{(x,y) \in X\times Y} f(x,y)\}
\end{gather}

Then:

$$
f(x^*,y^*) > f(x^*_I,y^*_I(x^*_I))
$$

However (this is the crucial step, I can't seem to argue convincingly about it, although it seems obvious to me):

$$
y^* \in \text{Image}(y^*_I(x))
$$

But if this is the case:

\begin{align}
f(x^*,y^*_I(x^*)) & =\displaystyle\max_{x} \displaystyle\max_{y} f(x,y) \\
&=f(x^*_I,y^*_I(x^*_I)),
\end{align}

giving the desired contradiction. Q.E.D.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is true and straightforward to prove is $\sup_x \sup_y = \sup_{x,y}$. If all the $\max$s happen to exist then the result follows from this.

Comment: Is the proof above valid?

Comment: I haven't looked at it as without some assumptions about the existence of maximizers it can't be true.

Comment: Assume it exists.

Comment: The argmax may be a set so you can't expect any uniqueness. Besides, it is straightforward to prove without resorting to argmaxs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $y$ we have  $f(x,y) \le \sup_{x'} f(x',y)$ and
$\sup_{x'} f(x',y) \le \sup_{y'} \sup_{x'} f(x',y') $. Hence
$\sup_{x,y} f(x,y) \le \sup_{y'} \sup_{x'} f(x',y') $.

In the other direction we have $f(x',y') \le \sup_{x,y} f(x,y)$ for all $x',y'$. Hence we have
$\sup_{x'} f(x,y) \le \sup_{x,y} f(x,y)$ for all $y$ and so
$\sup_{y'} \sup_{x'} f(x',y') \le \sup_{x,y} f(x,y)$ and so they are equal.

If each $\sup$ is attained then we can replace the $\sup$ by $\max$.